# SUMO: pass only TLS phases

Tags: ssl, simulator, duration, traffic, phase

I am using SUMO and for testing purposes I want to pass TLS phases. When declaring my TLS in an additional file, I am required to also pass the duration of the phase, but I want SUMO to fill that in. Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: sumo-user@lists.sourceforge.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is not.

The netconvert application generates fixed phase cycles for all intersections by default. It always uses 31s as the green phase duration (changeable using option --tls.green-time) and 6s for left turn phases. The yellow time is computed based on the minimum deceleration and there isn't even an all-red phase. So in short, you won't do much worse by pulling a number out of a hat.